# Lenovo Yoga 12 - Wacom Touchscreen stops functioning after 'Suspend'

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, lenovo, touchscreen, wacom

Have two of these laptops that I'm attempting to get the touchscreen to function properly on.
For seven days now and no success. . .
Installed Xubuntu 20 on the 2nd laptop. No dual booting or anything - just Linux.
Updated, did not update the kernel though - yet.
Hard Boot / Shutdown always works.
Function doesn't return after 'Suspend due to inactivity' or a 'Lid Close'.
Though if I 'Suspend from the menu' it does function after logging back in but only for a couple of tries and then it craps out.
And not if selected from the popup menu when power button is pushed.

Have not installed the .046 driver over on github - yet. Still on stock 2.0

Did install emesik's resume service found here: https://gist.github.com/emesik/d01679052ef3aeb83ebe87f46d223b12

Have not come across anything that will get this bloody wacom to function properly.
And I hate to say it, but it functions properly on the Redmond OS, which I'm desperately trying to get away from.